# Is this the correct way to protect a route in React using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

All the solution I found on the web seems complex , So I wrote this simple way of protecting a route , Is this also a correct way?

```
 <Route
    exact
    path="/Cart"
    component={() =>
    this.props.loading === true ? (
          <Cart />
   ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
   }
  />
```

Is there any cons to this approach ?

Comment: Unless it gives you error or some unexpected behaviour, you can use it.

Comment: but i didn't get any error unexpected behaviour ...

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter/getuserconfirmation-func.......check the docomation by reacttraining.....<Redirect>

Comment: then how can i protect my route ..connect with redux...

Comment: use HOC. find out more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and checkout [this blog post](https://crysislinux.com/limit-access-to-redux-apps-with-higher-order-components/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse the code in your case , But here is a simple solution you can follow.
It is called HOC , Higher Order Component . Which means you have to create a new component that holds the components you wish to protect

Example : `<Auth path="/login" component={Another} />`

Here Auth is the component that is protecting your components that needs to be protected

The Auth component should look like this :

```
function Auth({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        counter ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/sign" />
      }
    />
  );
}
export default Auth
```

Answer (score 4):

Everything should work with your example but you actually can't reuse your logic for other private components/routes so it's good to make some kind of wrapper for all authenticated routes.

This should be simple example of `PrivateRoute`

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                isAuthenticated() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
        />
    );
}
```

Usage

```
<PrivateRoute
    exact
    path="/Cart"
    component={Cart}
    isAuthenticate={() => checkAuth()} // or whatever method you use for checking auth
/>
```

Of course this could be well improved if you are using Redux, having async authentication check or some other complex logic, but this should give you a good start.

Comment: ok but how can i connect redux to it....check a value from redux

Comment: @sherinshaju Please check this package for full support of what you want https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper

Comment: What is the purpose of "compoent: Component" ? Can we use just "Component "instead?

Comment: Its just name change for "component", since you can't render with starting lowercase (e.g. <component {...props} />), thats why I change name to Component. I didn't use "Component" prop by default because I wanted to keep all props lowercase when using that component. And to answer your questions - yes we could just use { Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }.

Comment: Thanks man , Also I was able to connect redux with useSelector, but not with the connect method , Why do you think is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work, but you should use another component to protect routes

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to={
                {
                    pathname: '/login',
                    state: {
                        form: props.location
                    }
                }} />
    )} />
)
```

And in router file import PrivateRoute and use

```
 <PrivateRoute exact path='/Cart' component={EditPost} />
```

Comment: ok but how can i connect redux to it....check a value from redux